# Load XML content in javascript application

Tags: javascript

I develop a javascript application which display data from xml with charts and lists.
For now I put some sample files onto the server's directory that I load with :

```
$.ajax({ type: 'GET', url: 'data/default.xml', dataType: 'xml', ...})
```

The Xml files can be very heavy so when one of them is loaded I put the data in an IndexedDB.

In a second time I would like to let the visitor loads its own xml file by giving the filepath of the xml (f.i. : /home/user/sample.xml). I do not want to upload this file onto the server because I do not need it and it could be too big. But I do want to load those data in the IndexedDB and let the app displays data without any call to the server.

I do not know if browsers could work this way?
If they could, how can I do such a trick?

Comment: When you say indexed DB, do you have something specific in mind?

Comment: Yes, very specific as I mean IndexedDB : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Ajax to get data from a file on the client system, but [in sufficiently modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=file%20api) you can use the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). MDN has a [guide to the File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) that is friendlier then the specification.

Comment: I use "sufficiently modern browsers" as my application uses indexeddb which needs [sufficiently modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=indexeddb). That a great answer.